# What is the purpose of callback function in gmail api send message javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, gmail-api, sendmessage

I'm attempting to use the Gmail API Message Send service via my API key and have implemented the JavaScript code show in this tutorial.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send

I'm not sure what exactly the callback function input is meant for in this case. Is it supposed to be a redirect to another page on the website (like Response.Redirect does so in MVC)? Is there a particular gmail JavaScript code I should be using as the callback to get the user to sign out and exit the sign in session?

```
**
 * Send Message.
 *
 * @param  {String} userId User's email address. The special value 'me'
 * can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
 * @param  {String} email RFC 5322 formatted String.
 * @param  {Function} callback Function to call when the request is complete.
 */
function sendMessage(userId, email, callback) {
  // Using the js-base64 library for encoding:
  // https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-base64
  var base64EncodedEmail = Base64.encodeURI(email);
  var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
    'userId': userId,
    'resource': {
      'raw': base64EncodedEmail
    }
  });
  request.execute(callback);
}
```

I currently do have authorize and sign out buttons as well, so should the callback function just stay empty if I want the user to stay on the same web page after sending the message to their requested contact(s) via the Gmail API?

Comment: It's for anything you want.

Comment: The callback is just for the notifying you that the message was actually sent. A lot of things in javascript are asynchronous, so there is no way for you to be notified after  the message was actually sent except for using callbacks or promises.

Comment: Note that the code you are showing is example code from the API site, not code you have to use. you could call it differently if you wanted.

Comment: can I omit the variable callback from request.execute(callback)?